# Different materials on different sides of a mesh

Tags: materials

In Blender 2.80 I modeled a bottle cap and want a different material on each side - metallic with logo on the top, metallic silver inside. I set up a node tree that worked and then hit a snag: both materials appear in edit mode and rendered edit but only the top materials show in object mode and object render. What is causing this?

Below are screen shots:

[image: Edit mode and edit render]

[image: Object mode and object render]

[image: Node tree]

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer - backfacing on the Geometry node doesn't work when there's a Solidify modifier in play.  A bit more hair torn out but I got there!